# Get text of div children of input with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<input id="edit-name">
 <div class="description">
  Text Text Text
 </div>
</input>
```

I want to get the text inside div and change with other new text... but i don't know why my code doesn't work...

```
$('input[id="edit-name"]').find('.description').text('new new new');
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is invalid HTML to have child elements in an `input` element. What exactly do you want? Change text in an input text box? Or change text next to an input box?

Comment: use <button> instead of <input>  and use $('button[id="edit-name"]')

Comment: You need to change your HTML for this script to work.

Comment: Is true you are right! thanks a lot and sorry for the stupid question! :(